# Can't reply in the Slack thread making http post request with JSON

Tags: json, node.js, slack, slack-api, node-request

I want to reply in a slack thread via Slack API.

I have an object.

```
var msg = {
  text: 'test',
  thread_ts: '1513168789.000263' // it's right ts, I have checked 
}
```

I make the request

```
request.post({
  method: 'post',
  body: msg,
  json: true,
  url: '<incoming slack webhook>'
})
```

I expect to get the message to be replied in a thread, but it's just posted in a channel.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) if you want to send messages to a thread. The incoming webhook will not work (or at least there is no information in the documentation that it would support it).

`chat.postMessage` has a property called `thread_ts`, which you can use to address the correct thread.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291169/slack-get-thread-id-after-posting-message-using-incoming-web-hook/56291606#56291606) about webhooks and threads.

Comment: "Post your message as a reply in a thread
You can use Incoming Webhooks to make your message appear as a reply in a thread. Read our guide to threading messages to see the process."

Source: https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks

But you're right, there's no further documentation explaining how to do it.