# Slack - Get thread id after posting message using incoming web hook

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am using slack incoming web hook to post message to a channel. Here is my code

```
curl -X POST \
  https://hooks.slack.com/services/TXXXXXXXX/BXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "text": "Test message"
}'
```

I am getting `ok` as response. I need thread id(`thread_ts` or `ts`) to reply to that thread.

How can I get thread id while posting message to slack using incoming web hooks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Webhooks will not return IDs for your message. So you don't get the `thread_ts` and `ts`, which you both need to reply as thread.

Its technically possible to find your message through calling [`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) or if you listen to [message](https://api.slack.com/events/message) events. However, you would need some workaround to reliably match them (e.g. add you own IDs).

In summary: webhooks do not support threads. If you want to do threading you need to post your messages via the API (e.g. [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)) and not use webhooks. Webhooks are just meant to offer an easy and quick way for posting messages, but they dont't offer the full functionality.

Here is the [full guide](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-threading) on threads.

Comment: It's not entirely correct that incoming webooks doesn't support threads. It will post to a thread if you add `"thread_ts": "123456.123"` to the post message json data.