# Replying to a Thread using Slack Python Webhook API

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack-api

I'm creating a Python script to send messages to a slack channel. The message itself gets delivered fine, however when I try to start a thread and send replies to the thread, I am unable to get it working. The thread replies appear as a new parent message.

I'm using the slack-python-webhook module found at https://github.com/satoshi03/slack-python-webhook

```
import slackweb
import json
slack = slackweb.Slack(
    url="https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXX/XXXX/XXXXXX")


attachment = [{"text": "This is TEXT",
              "ts": "1564629129"
              }]


print(json.dumps(attachment))
slack.notify(attachments=attachment)

attachment = [{"text": "This is Thread REPLY",
              "thread_ts": "1564629129",
              "thread_ts": "1564629130"
              }]

print(json.dumps(attachment))
slack.notify(attachments=attachment)
```

I'd like to know what needs to be changed on the above code snippet so the second message will appear as a thread reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code won't work, because webhooks do not support threads. If you want to reply to threads you need to use the API methods for posting message (e.g. [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)).

That means you probably also need to use a different library, since the one mentioned in your question appears to only support webhooks.

Also your syntax is not correct. `thread_ts` is not a property of an attachment, but a parameter of a API method like `channel`.

I would recommend to check out the [slackclient](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient). It's the official Python library from Slack and has full support for all API methods incl. threads.

Here is how to reply to a thread with slackclient:

```
import slack
import os

# init slack client with access token
client = slack.WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN'])

# reply to a thread
response = client.chat_postMessage(
    channel="general",
    text="This is a reply",
    thread_ts="1561764011.015500"
)
assert response["ok"]
print(response)
```

See also this [official guide](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-threading) about threads and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291169/slack-get-thread-id-after-posting-message-using-incoming-web-hook/56291606#56291606) about webhooks and threads.